# JAXB binding to annotate all strings in all schemas under /schema with a custom annotation

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb, jaxb2, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

I have a dir */schemas* that has many *.xsd* files, and I want to annotate every field of type *String* with a custom annotation I created.

I'm using this plugin: *"org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-annotate:0.6.4".*

I think creating a jaxb binding config would be my ideal solution. I tried this:

```
<jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@type='xs:string']">
        <annox:annotateClass>@com.myapp.model.CustomAnnotation</annox:annotateClass>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

But in vain. Can you help? Thank you

Comment: Describe "in vain".

Comment: You probably want an XPath like `//xs:element[@type='xs:string']`. Also you'll need `multiple="true"` on your `jaxb:bindings`.

Comment: Also, `0.6.4` is a pretty old version. Latest are `1.0.4` and `1.1.0`.

Comment: hey @lexicore thanks. I'm now trying to annotate just one field in one specific schema: `<jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='someString']">
            <annox:annotate target="field">@com.app.custom.MyAnnotation</annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>` but unfortunately getting this error: `compiler was unable to honor this annox:annotate customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.` I'm pretty stuck now. Any advice?

Comment: You have to make sure that you attach these customizations to the right place. Make sure your XPath is correct.

Comment: I think the XPath is correct. From the error message, the line numbers are correct.

`[ant:xjc] [ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this annox:annotate customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
[ant:xjc]   line 53 of file:/some/path/mybinding.xjb
[ant:xjc] 
[ant:xjc] [ERROR] (the above customization is attached to the following location in the schema)
[ant:xjc]   line 167 of file:/some/other/path/myschema.xsd`

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. Alternatively send the MCVE as a pull request here: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin-support, say under `s/someproject`.